Prove or disprove a convergence in measure
I consider the sequence of functions defined by
$$
f_{n}(x)= 1_{[0,1/2]}(nx) - 1_{[1/2,1]}(nx), \quad x\in(0,1)
$$
It seems that I should prove that the sequence does not converge in measure to $0$ but I did not succeed. Instead, I have the feeling to have a good control on the measure of the set
$$
A_{\epsilon}^{n}= \{ x\in(0,1) : \lvert f_n(x)\rvert >\epsilon\}
$$
So I would like to expose my reasoning to know where I am wrong please.
Let $\epsilon>0$ and $\delta>0$. We will show that there exists a $N(\delta)\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\geq N(\delta)$ we have
$$
\mu(A_{\epsilon}^{n})\leq\delta
$$
First notice that $\lvert f_n(x)\rvert\leq 1$ so we can restrict ourself to $\epsilon\in(0,1)$.
Fix $N(\delta)=\frac{1}{\delta}$. Consider the two following cases where $\lvert f_n(x)\rvert =1$ :
$$
\frac{1}{2}<nx\leq 1\iff \frac{1}{2n}<x\leq\frac{1}{n}
$$
Or
$$
0<nx\leq\frac{1}{2} \iff 0<x\leq\frac{1}{2n}
$$
Then for all $x\in(\frac{1}{2n},\frac{1}{n}]$ or $x\in(0,\frac{1}{2n}]$ we have $\lvert f_n(x)\rvert = 1$. Thus we have for all $n\geq N(\delta)$ :
$$
\mu(A_{\epsilon}^{n})=\frac{1}{n}\leq\delta
$$
I would like to know where I my argument is incorrect please, I thought many times about it but I do not see the logical issue.
Thank you a lot !

The sequence converges a.e., hence also in measure, to $0$

Thank you ! I did not think to check through pointwise convergence although it is immediate here
